# Compiling with libusb?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, shared-libraries, ld, libusb-1.0

No matter what I run I get,

```
./main.c:1:10: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libusb.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Things tried

```
gcc ./main.c -l/usr/include/libusb-1.0/
gcc ./main.c -l/usr/include/
gcc ./main.c -L/usr/include/libusb-1.0/
gcc ./main.c -L/usr/include/
```

If I try

```
#include "libusb-1.0/libusb.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "libusb.h"
```

It compiles, but I get

```
/tmp/ccLn3qR2.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `libusb_init'
main.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid'
main.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
main.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `libusb_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get the same thing (the above errors) with

```
gcc ./main.c -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0
```

I see a lot of people getting similar errors, but I can find the solution. These seem to be [documented here](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/modules.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ended up working, was specifying the path in the `.h` file,

```
#include "libusb-1.0/libusb.h"
```

Which includes `/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h`. And, then compiling with,

```
gcc ./main.c -lusb-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, `brew install libusb` and then making sure the libraries are on your path (e.g. on Apple Silicon:

```
export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

is what worked for me.