# fatal error: libusb/libusb.h: No such file or directory librtlsdr install for GNU radio

Tags: cmake, libusb, gnuradio, libusb-1.0, rtl-sdr

Trying to install `rtl-sdr` (through `git clone git://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git`) thanks to the instructions [here](http://git%20clone%20git://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git) but can't go further than `make` in the first sequence of instructions:

```
cd rtl-sdr/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

At my first try I got the following error:

```
/rtl-sdr/src/librtlsdr.c:30:10: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
```

After locating this file:

```
/usr/include$ sudo locate libusb.h
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
```

I tried to replace the original `#include <libusb.h>` with `#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>` (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629619/how-to-install-libusb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226709/compiling-with-libusb)), which led to a different failure:

```
/rtl-sdr/build$ make
[  6%] Built target convenience_static
Scanning dependencies of target rtlsdr
[  9%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/rtlsdr.dir/librtlsdr.c.o
[ 12%] Linking C shared library librtlsdr.so
[ 28%] Built target rtlsdr
[ 31%] Linking C executable rtl_test
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_open'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_close'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_alloc_transfer'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_reset_device'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_handle_events_timeout'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_free_transfer'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_submit_transfer'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_dev_mem_free'
librtlsdr.so.0.6git: undefined reference to `libusb_cancel_transfer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/rtl_test.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'src/rtl_test' failed
make[2]: *** [src/rtl_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:138: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/rtl_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/rtl_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Note that this suggestion seems to be associated with a gcc compile option / link `--cflags libusb-1.0` or `-lusb-1.0` (cf. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629619/how-to-install-libusb) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13174)) that I don't know where to find (since I'm using `make`, without being used to it).

I also tried to replace the original `#include <libusb.h>` with `#include <usb.h>` (as seen [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ubuntu-9-10-include-libusb-libusb-h-802880/)) which led to:

```
/rtl-sdr/src/librtlsdr.c:97:2: error: unknown type name ‘libusb_context’
```

FYI `libusb-1.0-0-dev` and `libusb-dev` are already installed (as suggested [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/installing-rtl-sdr-cmake-error-libusb-1-0-required-to-compile-rtl-sdr-4175674171/), I tried, eventhough I guess I already had it installed...):

```
/usr/include$ sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0-dev
libusb-1.0-0-dev is already the newest version (2:1.0.21-2).

~$ sudo apt install libusb-dev
libusb-dev is already the newest version (2:0.1.12-31).
```

And already installed `rtl-sdr` using `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl-sdr
rtl-sdr is already the newest version (0.5.3-13).
```

About my system: **Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)**. This install aims at being able to use a DVB-T dongle with GNU Radio, which requires this `rtl-sdr` install.

**EDIT:** after @Tsyvarev answer

1. installed `pkg-config` with `sudo apt install pkg-config`
2. removed the first repository resulting from the initial `git clone`, new clean
   `git clone`, new `/build` etc and then `make`, which worked !

Removing the old repository clone & re-creating a clean `/build` was necessary, since trying to launch `make` in the old `/build` even after the install of `pkg-config` didn't work. Note that this implies that no change was needed on the `#include <libusb.h>` code line in `src/librtlsdr.c`.

As a side note, for those of you who end up here because they're trying to install the "RTL-SDR Source" block for GNU Radio, I suspect my problem was actually that I hadn't installed `gr-osmosdr` with `sudo apt install gr-osmosdr` after installing `rtl-sdr` with a simple `sudo apt-get install rtl-sdr`.

Comment: According to the project's [CMakeLists.txt](http://osmocom.org/projects/rtl-sdr/repository/revisions/master/entry/CMakeLists.txt#L72), it expects either libusb to be found with `pkg-config` or, if `pkg-config` is not available, libusb parameters should be filled **manually**: `LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS` should be set to include directory (`/usr/include/libusb-1.0` in your case) and `LIBUSB_LIBRARIES` should be set to the libusb library (for link with). Though it seems to be simpler to install `pkg-config`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, you solved my issue (cf. **EDIT** at the end of my question), if you write a real SO answer I'll gladly accept it !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Tsyvarev answer (see comment), which I put in the **EDIT:** at the end of my question. I re-post his solution here in order to close the question and mark it as solved.

1. installed `pkg-config` with `sudo apt install pkg-config`
2. removed the first repository resulting from the initial `git clone`, new clean
   `git clone`, new `/build` etc and then `make`, which worked !

Removing the old repository clone & re-creating a clean `/build` was necessary, since trying to launch `make` in the old `/build` even after the install of `pkg-config` didn't work. Note that this implies that no change was needed on the `#include <libusb.h>` code line in `src/librtlsdr.c`.

As a side note, for those of you who end up here because they're trying to install the "RTL-SDR Source" block for GNU Radio, I suspect my problem was actually that I hadn't installed `gr-osmosdr` with `sudo apt install gr-osmosdr` after installing `rtl-sdr` with a simple `sudo apt-get install rtl-sdr`.

Comment: tl;dr (for me): run `sudo apt install pkg-config`, clone a fresh copy of project and rerun `make`

Answer (score 3):

whole way:

```
sudo apt install pkg-config
sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0
git clone git://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git
cd rtl-sdr
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install
```